# Laptop screen turns off after short period of time

Tags: laptop, display, toshiba-laptop

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L500 and the screen has started going off after a second or 2 of use. For the brief time that the screen is on everything is clear and displays perfectly. Restarting the laptop or even just closing the screen and opening it again displays the screen for a second.

The laptop is otherwise working fine and I'm able to use it connecting to a TV through HDMI

What are the likely causes of this behaviour?

**UPDATE**

The Toshiba Diagnostics Tools reports a PASS on all tests.

Comment: Have you checked the screen timeout settings (and changed them, even if they seem correct)?

Comment: (Might help a little to know what version of what OS you're running.)

Comment: Has it ever worked right?

Comment: did you try to run the toshiba hardware test.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Dual boots with Linux Mint 14 and Windows 7. Also tried with an Ubuntu live CD. Same results.

Comment: @techie007 Yes it's worked fine for the last few years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds to me as if the inverter is failing. When the screen darkens, can you still faintly see the image (you will need to look closely)?

Comment: Over the years I have had to replace 2 of these. It cost me about 20 here in Toronto.

Comment: I can't see any faint image at all. But I'm starting to think it's the inverter.

Comment: Actually yes I can see a faint image, a lot fainter than I was expecting (it's barely visible at all). So would this backup the inverter failing?

Comment: Yes, that is a real sign.

Comment: Yep, sounds like the backlight has failed.

Comment: http://www.xpheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windowsxp-hardware/116912-lcd-inverter-vs-backlight.html#post498193

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with @Xavierjazz that the issue is most likely the inverter. The screen inverter is a small electrical circuit board responsible for taking in DC current from the motherboard and converting it to AC current to power the LCD display.

My second guess would be that the backlight of your computer is failing. The backlight illuminates the liquid crystals to produce the display. The inverter does power the backlight, but the backlight can fail independently of the inverter. See 
  http://ask.metafilter.com/92210/Backlight-or-Inverter-How-can-you-tell
for more information.

Since you mentioned that your laptop functions fine when hooked up to an external display, I would rule out the possibility of a defective motherboard or failing graphics card.

Comment: Uh, the inverter powers the backlight.